# Numpy arrays; How to replace elements with another array based on conditions?

Tags: python, numpy

Given two numpy arrays:

```py
import numpy as np 
A = np.array([[0, 5, 0],
             [1, 0, 1],
             [0, 2, 0]])

B = np.array([[0, 7, 0],
             [1, 0, 1],
             [0, 1, 0]])
```

How can I replace elements in A where the same i,j index is greater in B.

I would have thought that this:

```py
A[A < B] = B
```

Would work, but it doesn't.

Expected result:

```py
[[0, 7, 0],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A[A < B]` has a very different shape than `B`, so you can't do that assignment. You wanted to do

```
A[A < B] = B[A < B]
```

A bit more efficiently, you could say

```
mask = A < B
A[mask] = B[mask]
```

Or you could just evaluate the maximum for each element:

```
A = np.maximum(A, B)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution by conditioning `B` to give a similarly sized array and then setting from its results:

```py
A[A < B] = B[B > A]
```